# How to fix NPM EJSONParse in this package.json file?

Tags: node.js, json, npm, npm-scripts

After I prepared for auto scripts and installing few packages to automate my tasks, I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! file C:\Users\windw\Desktop\bootstrap4\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 455 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "confusion",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": '
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Below is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "copyfonts": "copyfiles -f node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/fonts",
    "imagemin": "imagemin img/* --out-dir='dist/img'",
    "usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run imagemin && npm run copyfonts && npm run usemin"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "htmlmin": "0.0.7",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "onchange": "^6.1.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
    "usemin-cli": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-social": "5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9"
  }
}
```

How can I fix the NPM EJSONParse error?

Comment: Have you tried using an editor with syntax highlight? You would immediately see where is the problem in your JSON.

Comment: Or, validate your JSON [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: thanks fixed that problem in syntax

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma at the end of the 12th line in your `package.json` file.

Presently it looks like this:

```
"watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
```

It should look like this:

```
"watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\"",
```

Note the comma at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred when you are somehow  missing `","` comma. and when you use comma in last line if not required also it happens. If this issue showed, you need to review your `pakage.json` file.